# Is it possible to use command substitution in an applescript call to `do shell script`?

Tags: bash, applescript, sh, process-substitution

I have an automator service that I was updating to handle a series of input files in combination (instead of serially, like it currently does).  It does a bunch of stuff, but in one component of it, I need to process the contents of N files and hand the processing of the output of each file off to a single `paste` command to combine it all and further process the combo.  On the command line, I would do it with process substitution, e.g.:

```
paste <(commands processing file 1) <(commands processing file 2) ... | other processing commands
```

But if I do this from inside an applescript, like this:

```
set output to (do shell script "paste <(commands processing file 1) <(commands processing file 2) ... | other processing commands")
```

I get an error from applescript:

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Finder got an error: sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `paste <(commands processing file 1) <(commands processing file 2) ... | other processing commands'”
```

I learned that this is because `sh` doesn't do the fancy stuff that bash does, e.g. process substitution.

I know I could just write temporary files to accomplish my goal, but I'd rather not have to if there's a way around it.

I tried getting around this by using `bash -s`:

```
set output to (do shell script "bash -s <<'EOF'" & return & "paste <(commands processing file 1) <(commands processing file 2) | other processing commands" & return & "EOF")
```

But that yields the same error.

Any idea how to accomplish this without having to write temporary files?

***UPDATE***: I realized that I pared the problem down too much.  There is a bit more to it.  The series of commands I am using (including the `paste` command mentioned already), includes one-liner code that contains variables and single-quotes, so the solution would need have to prevent shell interpolation of variables and not interfere with single-quotes.  I will update the toy example below to include those details.

---

**Toy example (applescript):**

file 1:

```
this is the first test
```

file 2:

```
this is the second test
```

applescript:

```
set file1 to "~/file1.txt"
set file2 to "~/file2.txt"
set output to (do shell script "paste <(head " & file1 & " | perl -ne 'chomp;print(substr($_,0,4),qq(\\n))') <(head " & file2 & " | perl -ne 'chomp;print(substr($_,-4),qq(\\n))')"
display dialog output
```

Expected output:

```
this    test
```

Note, there are other variables and another command (awk) using single quotes.

Comment: BTW It's **Process Substitution** you are using, not **Command Substitution**, and the later works in `sh` where the former does not.

Comment: Whoops. I do that all the time.  I can never remember the name.

Comment: Since you are doing this in **Automator**, can you use a **Run Shell Script** _action_ instead of a **Run AppleScript** _action_ and `do shell script` _command_. Mixing **AppleScript** and _shell scripting_ can be quite a pain, as you've discovered.

Comment: Not with fancy dialogs. It's a big script. It works great in version 1, just handles the files independently. I'll send a link to the gist if you're interested.

Comment: If it's not broke then why are you trying to fix it? (More of a rhetorical question.)

Comment: Trying to add a new feature. Currently, with the files processed independently, there's no way to tell what the combinations are that are present in the files. And if there is more than 1 combination amiss, the amount of work to solve it scales up. Combining the lines yields the most accurate solution.

Comment: OK, well, I got a sanity check to work using `bash -s <<'EOF'`.  I actually needed to *remove* the escape characters. And my issue with no output must have something to do with something unrelated, like other escape characters or something. I can see a path forward at least. If it weren't for the quotes, escapes, and variables, I think your solution would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my gosh!  Right after I posted this, I realized that all I needed to do was escape the parens.  I was on the right track with `bash -s`!  I think writing out the question was just the process I had to go through to realize the answer!

```
set output to (do shell script "bash -s <<'EOF'" & return & "paste \\<\\(commands processing file 1\\) \\<\\(commands processing file 2\\) | other processing commands" & return & "EOF")
```

I can't believe I didn't see it before posting the question!

Comment: Alright, well, maybe I was too quick to post.  I don't get the error anymore, but I'm not getting any output this way either.  And if I display the command in a dialog and try to use it on the command line, I get errors, so I'm not going to select my own answer until I've figured that out.  Ugh.

Comment: Oh wait, I think it's because the command from the dialog still has the escape characters... So I think the above is correct.  The `sh` will remove those escape characters.  And it's now back to debugging other stuff... If I get this all confirmed, I'll be back with an update.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```applescript
set file1 to "~/file1.txt"
set file2 to "~/file2.txt"
set output to do shell script "bash -c \"paste <(head " & file1 & ") <(head " & file2 & ")\""
display dialog output
```

---

[image]

Comment: Ugh.  So I'm trying this, but I've got dollar signs in the actual process substitution commands that I'm struggling to deal with (since your answer adds a pair of double-quotes), so I went back to the `bash -s <<EOF` strategy. When I do that, I'm not getting an error, but I'm not getting output (in 1 case) either. Yet if I put the full command in `display dialog` in that case, copy and paste it into the terminal, it works as expected!... There's more to it, but it's too complicated for a comment.

Comment: Got it all working using the `bash -s` thing.  It was the escape characters.  It's funny, escapes caused no AS error, but the subshell was silently failing with a paste usage (or no file found error).  I had added the escapes before trying to call bash explicitly and had kept them thinking `sh` parsing needed them, but that turns out to not be the case. Again, I think your solution would have worked if it weren't for the nested quotes and variable. Maybe I'll update the question with that wrinkle and you can include that in your answer, so I can select it... though I'll have to do that later..

Comment: Here's the end result: https://gist.github.com/hepcat72/3319f03f3b9e75ad2fa6e7f3d63c690b#file-guess-barcodes-scpt